# How can I generate Sequence Diagram from a C# solution in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sequence-diagram

How can I generate Sequence Diagram from a solution in Visual Studio 2013?

The VS solution has some C# classes.

Comment: What sort of state machine?

Comment: @canton7, sequence diagram.

Comment: 1) A state machine isn't a sequence diagram, and 2) what exists in the C# solution which Visual Studio could use to generate the diagram?

Comment: Use one of `PSTricks` , `TikZ`, `Asymptote`, `Metapost`, etc.

Comment: When you say *"generate"*, do you mean "create and edit" or are you talking about automatically inferring a control flow (or data flow?) graph from the code and automatically turning it into a sequence diagram?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Enterprise version of Visual Studio, the context menu in a public method (right-click the method name) should provide you an option for creating a sequence diagram.

You may read more about it here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-sequence-diagram-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: This is true but for early versions of visual studio, they removed at least in the 2017 and 2019

Comment: Oh! I have not tried them. It is sad that MS is not supporting the developer community.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/
I use it for front end (js version), but it has similar functionality for all supported platforms.it's super powerful

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

1. go to your desire class just Right click on the method
2. popup will appear select 4th option Generate Sequence Diagram
3. another window will appear "Generate Sequence Diagram window" 
   select your desire project or solution then ok.

Comment: this option isn't available in VS 2013.

Comment: @user366312 its available in VS 2013 Enterprise.