# VS2019 Class Diagrams: Show association between Fields and Methods/Constructors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, associations, class-diagram

A class `StringSplitter` has the field `ObjectifiableMatches`.
Another class `String2ObjectConverter` takes the variable `ObjectifiableMatches` as argument.
Can I show this relation in a VS2019 class diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relation between the two classes according to the UML semantics:

- in `StringSplitter`, `ObjectifiableMatches` is a property of type `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurentBag<string>>`
- in `String2ObjectConverter`, `ObjectifiableMatches` is an argument of type  `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurentBag<string>>`

First of all, the same name is just a coincidence.  In fact, the name of the operation's argument does not matter in its signature.

Then, you could indeed use `StringSplitter`'s property as argument of the `String2ObjectConverter`'s operation. But you could also use any other object of that type.  And why would you:  `StringSpitter` does not even know `String2ObjectConverter`.

So there seems to be no association and no direct dependency between both classes either. In consequence, there is no reason to show any relation between these classes.

The only thing that you could show, would be two dependencies: one from each of these classes to the class `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurentBag<string>>` that both need.

***Note**: I use "property" and "operation" from the UML terminology instead of "field" and "method" from C#*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that the 2 classes have no association is a good thing since i wanted the code to be decoupled and changable. The reason I ask is I have a code review meeting tomorrow and I wanted to visualize the flow of my code.

Comment: @MichaelS I suspected something like this.  But a class diagram shows structural relationships, and is not suitable to show the flow. You may then consider using a [sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56392473/3723423) to show the scenario of interactions